# Why would binding.pry cause Rspec Selenium test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, pry

I'm seeing some really interesting behavior. Consider a basic rails setup, a user can create a new object `Order` or edit an existing one. There's one controller action that does both (as you can see on the code below).

I'm running a feature test to check that the EDIT correctly works. The test uses Selenium and correctly sets up my DatabaseCleaner strategy to truncation and overrides the default transactional features. As a result, the following tested code will pass:

```
# Controller code
def create_or_update
    ...
    if order_params[:id]
        @order = Order.find(order_params[:id].to_i)
        @order.assign_attributes(modified_order_params)
    else
        @order = Order.new(modified_order_params)
    end
    if @order.save
        redirect_to "success"
    else
        render params[:page]
    end
    ...
end

# RSpec code
describe "set up order", js: true, driver: :selenium, type: :feature do
  before do
    @order = Order.create({...})
    visit "/edit/#{@order.id}"
  end

  describe "when user submits changes" do
    before do
      find(".order[data-id='1'] [name='specification']").set("red color")
      find(".submit-changes").click
      sleep(5)
    end

    it "should save changes" do
      order = Order.last
      order.specification.should == "red color"
    end
  end
end
```

Again, the above code passes just fine, and I can confirm visually manually that it does pass looking at the resulting page.

HOWEVER, if I inject a `binding.pry` into the controller code like so:

```
# Controller code
def create_or_update
    ...
    binding.pry
    if order_params[:id]
        @order = Order.find(order_params[:id].to_i)
        @order.assign_attributes(modified_order_params)
    else
        @order = Order.new(modified_order_params)
    end
    if @order.save
        redirect_to "success"
    else
        render params[:page]
    end
    ...
end
```

The test suddenly fails. Why? because of this:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Order with 'id'=1 occurred at /Users/jamesdong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
```

And in the `binding.pry` environment I get mixed results. Sometimes this happens:

```
Order.count
=> 1
Order.last.inspect
=> "#<Order id: 1 ...
```

Other times this happens:

```
Order.count
=> 0
```

Note that even when the Order CAN be found, the test fails with the same error that the order with ID of 1 can't be found.

I'm relatively new to using `binding.pry` but this is the first time it's been UNHELPFUL and caused me to waste hours of time. I didn't see anything in the docs that would help clarify. Does anyone else have experience here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing apps with JS capable drivers the app is run in a different thread than the tests.  This means when you add binding.pry to the controller code, it gets paused but the test thread may continue on, finishes/fails the test and then database cleaner is run to clean up your objects.  If you're relatively quick in your pry session you'll find your objects ( within the sleep(5) timeframe )  - otherwise they may be cleaned up and gone.  Also it's telling you the error is occurring in an after hook, but you don't show any after hooks, only before, in your code???

Note: using `sleep()` in a test with Capybara is generally frowned upon since it means your tests will take longer than necessary.  Instead you should be checking a visual change on the page that indicates the action has completed - something like

```
expect(page).to have_text('Order updated')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/success')
```

etc. depending on exactly what your app does or how it shows that the update was successful